# Debugging assistance with Windows Error Reporting for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nullreferenceexception

Can anyone explain to me how to go about debugging a System.NullReferenceException that occurred on a user's machine when I'm not able to reproduce the problem on my machine?  I do not know how to determine the source/location of the error since I cannot reproduce it.

The user was running the app and at some point Windows Error Reporting appeared saying

"Application" has stopped working.  Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.

[image: Windows Error Reporting]

Since I am not able to reproduce the issue manually, is it possible for me to use all of the "Problem Signature" information to determine exactly where in the application the problem is?

Comment: You should be able to get a dmp file that you can load into windbg (you'll have to download the windows debgugging tools) and when you click on the !analyze -v command, it will show the stack where the error occurred.

Comment: Thank you, Peter.  I hope the user has one he can provide to me, so I will report back here once I find out.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2010 Pro or better, loading the dmp file right into Visual Studio might provide useful information as well (my experience has been with windbg).

Comment: Where can I tell the user to locate the dump file?  Will there definitely be one (I never explicitly wrote any code to create dump files from the application, but hopefully .NET or Windows handles that for me?)  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, this link seems to imply that I can do it without a dmp file?  Though I'm not able to decipher exactly how to do it from this link because I'm not an expert and this doesn't have step by step detail. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx

Comment: Location of dump files is configured in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\DumpFolder  See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That link says "Applications that do their own custom crash reporting, including .NET applications, are not supported by this feature."

Comment: This is a hint to you that you need to be catching and logging exceptions at the top level of your application. When logging, log at least `ex.ToString()` for an exception caught as `ex`.

Comment: Thanks, John.  First order of business after learning about this error I *did* add top-level handling for unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

After wrestling for a while with this, I was eventually able to decipher and use the instructions at this page (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx) to find the location of the unhandled exception.

Name:        MyApplication.Form_MyForm.Dispose(Boolean)

Unfortunately, while it did point me to the particular form where the exception occurred, since the exception is in the Form.Dispose method and not one of the methods that I wrote, I'm not sure what I can do to troubleshoot further.